# Editing GSA XSLT to replace part of URL

Tags: xslt, google-search-appliance

I am trying to edit the default styelsheet for the GSA.  My goal is to change the parts of a URL that match pattern old.mycompany.com/restofurl to info.mycompany.com/restofurl.  Not only am I new to XSLT, but I'm struggling on figuring out where in the default XSLT should go.

I'm timid to post the stylesheet in case it is proprietary to Google. If anyone has experience in this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to change the search results URL, the results links, some external CSS, or something else?  In general, changing anything in the XSLT is not a good idea, except the very specific sections marked in the stylesheets.